# Broad leaf commerce cart

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I don't see cart model in broad leaf commerce Database model and also in code, order object is used as cart.

I will appreciate if someone from broadleaf commerce help me out to understand that why cart is not there.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Broadleaf, a cart is an Order with a status of IN_PROCESS. We do not think of a cart as separate from a real Order; it just represents an Order that has not yet been submitted.

[Javadoc for the various statuses of an Order.](http://javadocs.broadleafcommerce.com/core/3.1.8-GA/org/broadleafcommerce/core/order/service/type/OrderStatus.html)

Comment: I believe cart should get converted in order once checkout flow starts, before that it should be cart only. Abandon cart can be cleared based on TTL or any job.If user is willing to add more item in same cart then will it added in db cart is IN_PROCESS or ORDER status is IN_PROCESS? Thanks for pointing me OrderStatus. Do we have some more order status & sub status combination or just one Order status.

Comment: Order can be in IN_PROCESS in multiple ways i.e. Credit card authorization, fulfillment, settlement, refund or chargeback etc. I hope there are multiple type of status against a single order which helps to determine order life cycle.

Comment: First of all, there is no conversion from cart to order once the checkout flow starts. Throughout the whole checkout flow, the order is just IN_PROCESS until the user hits submit and the Order goes through the checkout workflow. At the end of the checkout workflow, the order is changed to SUBMITTED.

Comment: In the Broadleaf framework currently, there is only IN_PROCESS. Various other stages of the order lifecycle can be determined based on what the order already has. For instance, if the user has already put in shipping information, then there will be an address on the fulfillment group of an Order, etc. For the other things you have there (fulfillment, settlement, refund) those are OMS (Order Management System) features. Broadleaf has some of these concept in the OMS module which introduces the idea of a FulfillmentOrder where the lifecycle after an order is submitted is maintained.

Comment: Thats great, I was looking for OMS. Thanks for share it.